# Communication between home Wireguard w/o public IP and another Wireguard instance in a VPS

Tags: networking, vpn, vps, wireguard

I'm running a Wireguard server ("**wg-home**", 192.168.7.50/24) and other services at home, which I'd like to access from outside my own network.

Unfortunately, my ISP does not provide a public IP, so I'm looking for a configuration that allows me to easily connect from the Internet to inside my LAN.

My idea is to keep an active outgoing connection from inside my LAN to my VPS in which is installed another instance of Wireguard ("**wg-vps**").
The VPS has a direct connection to the Internet via a public address (example 90.100.200.70).

Both the wg-home and the wg-vps are running on Debian based operative systems.

The question is: how can I configure the two instances of Wireguard in order to allow me to connect to the wg-vps public endpoint and being able to reach all devices inside my LAN (192.168.7.x/24)?

Thanks in advance for your help